# How to get a value which is depending on it from a JSON object in java

Tags: java, json

I have a below JSON Object. I would like to get the "**href**" value where "**name**" = "**hl7sender2appender**" from 2 objects of "**data**". Actually, I have more than 2 objects in my scenario and dependency is the "**name**".

```
{
"total": 2,
"data": [
    {
        "name": "flightfarejaws",
        "id": "local$aca210b4-b94e-4401-b1c9-28d103c6e601",
        "lastModified": "Wed, 5 Mar 2014 16:30:37.929 IST",
        "applications": [
            "local$0176c872-73f9-4302-923d-73c0c402fedd"
        ],
        "href": "http://localhost:8585/mmc/api/deployments/local$aca210b4-b94e-4401-b1c9-28d103c6e601",
        "status": "DEPLOYED",
        "servers": [
            "local$f08ab005-11d6-41d2-824c-dab55b993a71"
        ],
        "clusterIds": [],
        "reconciled": false,
        "clusterNames": []
    },
    {
        "name": "hl7sender2appender",
        "id": "local$563beec8-ec05-470f-ae54-0f53d226d2c1",
        "lastModified": "Mon, 3 Mar 2014 16:15:45.816 IST",
        "applications": [
            "local$a81a3780-2a93-4261-9d0f-1f54cb976742"
        ],
        "href": "http://localhost:8585/mmc/api/deployments/local$563beec8-ec05-470f-ae54-0f53d226d2c1",
        "status": "UNDEPLOYED",
        "servers": [
            "local$f08ab005-11d6-41d2-824c-dab55b993a71"
        ],
        "clusterIds": [],
        "reconciled": false,
        "clusterNames": []
    }
]}
```

Can anyone please tell me the best way to achieve this in Java.

Comment: Use the [JSON Java library](http://www.json.org/java/) to parse and evaluate the object.

Comment: Use either GSON or Jackson libraries - they're both improvements over the json.org parser.